# Could not find gem 'ffi' when run simple rails template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, bundler, ffi, libnotify

I'm getting error when try run my recept:

and run following commands:

```
$> rails _3.2.8_ new demo_app -T

$> cd demo_app

$> rake rails:template LOCATION=https://raw.github.com/gist/3752746/a259f4307b65493f4b7043bd78f30efa3ba6191e/test.rb
```

Recept is here https://raw.github.com/gist/3752746/a259f4307b65493f4b7043bd78f30efa3ba6191e/test.rb

Then i getting following error

```
Could not find gem 'ffi (~> 1.0.0) ruby', 
which is required by gem 'libnotify (= 0.5.9) ruby', in any of the sources.
```

When I use manual installation with copy-paste gems and running 'bundle install' everything works good.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gem install ffi`

then run that again.

Comment: i had this with a new install of a ruby on mountain lion.  once you get passed it all is good. Satisfied or not, lol.

Comment: Probably Mac users are happier then Linuxes'. But it still doesn't work

Comment: Are you on a linux? i thought libnotify was for like growl on mac? could explain something at least.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
require 'bundler'

# do your template gem adding stuff...

Bundler.with_clean_env do
  run 'bundle install'
end
```

Reference: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3153

Comment: It should be documented on the guide for making templates, right?

Comment: probably, it has been already solved. or it's just environment specific configuration when the issue appears.

Comment: I've just faced this issue with a fresh new app and an app template. I'ts a non issue as long as it is documented.